# OpenCV with Gstreamer streams with delay, slow and artifacts

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, gstreamer

There are delays in my gstreamer pipeline using OpenCV. I want to read rtsp stream, get frames, modify them and then output in a new rtsp/tcp/udp streams.

Delay **results** that produces my pipeline in opencv:
[image]
[image]

The code below reads rtsp stream and output to tcp these frames. But OpenCV gives me delay during streaming rtsp camera example as well as using **videotestsrc**. Can someone help and explain what to do with my pipeline to make it work as fast as possible?

I want to get speed compared to **gst-launch**. There are no artifacts with delay and slowing using gst-launch compared to OpenCV

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://170.93.143.139/rtplive/470011e600ef003a004ee33696235daa ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! tcpserversink  port=8554 host=0.0.0.0
```

**P.S** This is the only one working pipeline that I could get with free rtsp camera. btw, I could not stream into rtsp, only to tcp

```py
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtspsrc location=rtsp://170.93.143.139/rtplive/470011e600ef003a004ee33696235daa ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
f_width = int(cap.get(3))
f_height = int(cap.get(4))
f_fps = int(cap.get(5))
print(f_width, f_height, f_fps)

out = cv2.VideoWriter('appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! tcpserversink  port=8554 host=0.0.0.0', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER,0, 20, (f_width,f_height), True)

while cap.isOpened():
  read_start = time.time()
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  read_end = time.time() - read_start
  print('read:', read_end)
  print(ret)
  if ret:
    out_start = time.time()
    out.write(frame)
    out_wtite = time.time() - out_start
    print('write', out_wtite)

  print('-'*10)

cap.release()
out.release()
```

The speed results on my PC for cap read and write.

```
----------
read: 0.06638693809509277
write 0.00010824203491210938
----------
read: 0.06541061401367188
write 0.00011515617370605469
----------
read: 0.06638312339782715
write 0.00010037422180175781
----------
read: 0.06667900085449219
write 0.00010275840759277344
----------
read: 0.066192626953125
write 0.00012063980102539062
----------
read: 0.06572628021240234
write 9.441375732421875e-05
----------
read: 0.0661618709564209
write 0.00011110305786132812
```

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution: Just minimize x264enc bitrate and minimize writing fps and all works as a charm. Believe it'll help someone

Comment: Could you share the code please? I don't know what you exactly mean, I am having the same issue. Thanks in advance